# use same table id in different databases

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have two databases, one for dev, one for maintenance for example, both databases have same tables, someone add a record on Table1 (which is a dictionary table) in database dev but he forgot to insert it on Table1 in maintenance so ids becomes not sincronizad and we end up with same names but different ids in both databases.

What's the best way to keep these two tables in sync, using sequences from outside? triggers?

Comment: RedGate's [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) can help keep table data consistent among environments.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to avoid using the identity as the primary key. Identities make good clustering keys, but not necessarily a primary key.

Otherwise you could schedule a database refresh from Prod to Dev but you'd be wiping out all the work in Dev so I'd only do that once a month.

Or an SSIS package that reloads the data for that table from Prod, using the Identity Insert option.

Comment: I was just thinking if there was something better :( Redgate is good but we don't have it

Comment: A scheduled SSIS job, the third option I included, does not use any 3rd party tools. As long as you are only updating one table, that is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion: It will be easier for you to maintain.

Since these are NOT prod databases, keep one of the database tables as the actual source of truth. Overwrite the other one on a regular basis either through an SSIS job or a manual data import utility (provided by default with SQL Server installation)